# Pandas python - Como verificar se uma "tuple" de elementos de duas Series está contido num set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Eu tenho um "set" de "tuples" da seguinte forma 
set = {(2, 3), (2, 4), (5, 5)}

Meu DataFrame é assim:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'one': [1,2,4,1], 'two' : [5,3,2,2]})
```

Eu quero verificar se em cada linha a "tuple" formada pelos elementos das duas séries está contido no set. O resultado desejado seria esse:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1,2,4,1], 'two' : [5,3,2,2], 'three' : [False, True, False, False]})
```

Eu tentei:

```
df['three'] =  ((df['one'], df['two']) in set)
```

Não funcionou e me deu a seguinte mensagem de erro: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Como conseguir o resultado desejado? Obrigado

Comment: Estamos no [pt.so], poderia traduzir sua pergunta?

Comment: Nossa, não tinha notado. Vou resolver isso.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri uma solução:

```
df['A'] = list(zip(df.one, df.two))
df['three'] = df['A'].isin(set)
```

Comment: Ruan, A ideia do zip é boa mas parece-me que não funcionaria o isin... Poderias confirmar?

Answer (score 0):

Usando zip e listas em compreensão:

```
z=zip(......)
df['three'] = [x in set for x in z]
```